# Android screen text overlay

Tags: android

I need to display text on the screen like that

[image]

How can I do that? Do I need to sign the application?

I already checked [Overlay screen on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658533/overlay-screen-on-android) but the method doesen't seems to work from a service.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to create an overlay on top of other apps also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to add graphical elements using WindowManager to display stuff on top of other stuff (within my app and outside) from a service.

Take a look at how we do that in GlobalTouchService from our project ([Reach.io](https://github.com/jinkim608/reach.io)).

If you are just displaying something and interacting with those elements you added, this method will be sufficient. Interacting with other apps(outside your app) through that interface requires additional stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Try it by using `RelativeLayout` and [View.html#bringToFront()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#bringToFront()) method

Check this: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23669036/1614378)